# Flask not working in Virtualenv setup

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

SetUp

> VirtualBox | Ubuntu Server 12.04.2
>   (flaskve)vks@UbSrVb:~/flaskve$ python --version
>   Python 2.7.3
>   ifconfig
>   192.168.1.100  (the bridge interface on which i interact with VirtualBox)

code I am trying to run.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='192.168.1.100', port=8080, debug=True)
```

When I do

```
(flaskve)vks@UbSrVb:~/flaskve$ python start.py 
(flaskve)vks@UbSrVb:~/flaskve$
```

It does not run or do anything, it just returns back to command prompt. Although I am running in debug=True mode.
I then made a new VirtualEnv and install bottle in that. When I tried to run helloworld it shows the same behaviour.
However I then started the python shell on the same virtualenv, imported bottle modules and ran

> ```
> >>> from bottle import route, run
> >>> run(host='192.168.1.100', port=8081, debug=True)
> Bottle v0.11.6 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
> Listening on http://192.168.1.100:8081/
> Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
> ```

What could be problem here ? 
Even debug does not show anything.
Following link is the output of `python -v start.py`
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5713138/

Comment: Try starting Python with the -v arg. `python -v start.py`

Comment: Is that code you pasted the content of `start.py`?

Comment: @DazWorrall The code I pasted is of start.py

Comment: That's pretty impressive - what happens when you start a python shell in Flask's virtual env and run `import flask.signals` (since that's causing the hard exit in your paste link)?

Comment: did you create your virtual env with --no-site-packages and explicitly import flask into that? Perhaps there's some fault in the creation of the virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

The first example uses Flask, not bottle. Maybe you are confusing your code snippets here? :)